# Is it possible to use two or more repeating groups (not nestead) on same page in PDF template. BI Publisher

Tags: pdf-generation, bi-publisher

`fProcessor.process()` method stuck when PDF template with two repeating groups on same page is used.

Is it possible to use two or more repeating groups (not nested) on same page?

```
FormProcessor fProcessor = new FormProcessor();    

fProcessor.setTemplate(args[0]);  // Input File (PDF) name    

fProcessor.setData(args[1]);    // Input XML data file name    

fProcessor.setOutput(args[2]);  // Output File (PDF) name             

fProcessor.process();
```

Comment: How did you specify/code the repeating groups? What was the error?

Answer (score 0):

Received following reply from oracle support

PDF templates do not support multiple nor nested loops.

You can only use one.

Comment: Hi @usman, how about repeating group in 'document-repeat-elementname' tag? Will this be recognized as a nested loop?